# List validation exclude a validation if a field contain certain value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-validation

I have the following list validation:-

```
=IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)=IF(Status="Commission Paid",IF([Commission Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)=IF(Status="Delivered",IF([Order Delivered Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

to check for 3 columns, but i need to add the following to the above formula:-

if a column named "Reference Number" contain the following text "-CANCEL-" to always return true for this validation `=IF(Status="Commission Paid",IF([Commission Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)`? so can anyone advice how i can do so?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the second formula as following:

```
=IF(Status="Commission Paid",OR(IF([Commission Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-CANCEL-",[Reference Number])))),TRUE)
```

And the new list validation formula should be:

```
=IF(Status="Invoiced",IF([Customer Invoiced Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)=IF(Status="Commission Paid",OR(IF([Commission Paid Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),NOT(ISERROR(FIND("-CANCEL-",[Reference Number])))),TRUE)=IF(Status="Delivered",IF([Order Delivered Date]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```